# Where can I configure Chromium's default command line arguments?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, command-line, arguments, chrome

I've seen lots of places people have suggested to store command line arguments,

- `~/.config/google-chrome-flags.conf`
- `~/.config/chromium-flags.conf`
- `/etc/default`,

My version of chromium doesn't seem to be using these, and none of these locations are mentioned in `man chromium-browser`. Where would I best store a command line flag that I want to be supplied to `chromium-browser`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found joy in,

```
/etc/chromium-browser/default
```

Which is set by the `CHROMIUM_FLAGS` options.

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--incognito --password-store=gnome"
```