# Hiding Chromium tab bar, omnibar (address bar) and window decorations?

Tags: configuration, i3, chrome

I'm using both i3 and Chromium. I love Chromium tabs, but hate having that tab-bar there if there is only one tab open. I want it to behave more like a terminal (sanely)

- If there is more than one tab, I see the tab bar.
- If there is one tab, I can't see the tab bar.
- If there is no tabs the window closes.

I believe this was at one point the default behavior too. Currently I want to have a very small chromium browser window in i3 which is very much centered around minimizing wasted space.

I see lots of people with the same question online, and no answer.

Ideally, I want to simply **tone down window decorations**. Ideally, Chrome without Window Decorations, Tab Bars, or the Omnibar bars. That would be ideal.

Something like `--kiosk` mode outside of full-screen mode seems ideal.

---

Note: **What I do NOT want is Full-screen mode**.  I want other things to be open at the same.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, here is what I found worked.

- Install the surfing [SurfingKeys, vim modal extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/surfingkeys/gfbliohnnapiefjpjlpjnehglfpaknnc) and use `;u` (new tab) and `;U` to edit the URL
- Add `--app=http://duckduckgo.com` to the command line arguments for Chrome. Any window with this has tabs **DISABLED**. This is a major downside and not the desired effect.

  - Globally, this can be accomplished by [editing `/etc/chromium-browser/default`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/483770/3285)
  - Locally this can be done with a i3 hotkey to open an undecorated naked Chrome, for example something like this will allow you to open up Chrome in three different modes,

    ```
        bindsym $mod+i               exec chromium-browser --app=http://duckduckgo.com
        bindsym $mod+Shift+i         exec chromium-browser
        bindsym $mod+Shift+Control+i exec chromium-browser --incognito
    ```

Note: you have to set a homepage. Extensions do not run from `about://blank` and the like.

### Relevant parts of my conf

What I do is actually slightly more complex, I have a mode for spawning Chrome:

```
mode "chrome" {
  bindsym c exec chromium-browser                             , mode "default"
  bindsym a exec chromium-browser --app=http://duckduckgo.com , mode "default"
  bindsym s exec chromium-browser --incognito                 , mode "default"
  bindsym Return mode "default"
  bindsym Escape mode "default"
}
bindsym $mod+c mode "chrome"
```

This works well for me. As `$mod+c, a` spawns a chrome with no decorations.